# SQL Server TRY...CATCH Is Not Catching An Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, try-catch

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC N'EXEC sp_testlinkedserver N''[MyLinkedServer]'';';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'LinkedServerDown' AS Result
    RETURN
END CATCH
SELECT TOP(1) FirstName FROM [MyLinkedServer].TestDatabase.dbo.Customer
```

My first experience with using a TRY...CATCH in SQL Server does not have me impressed so far.

I've stopped the SQL Service on my linked server to attempt to test a situation where our linked server is down, inaccessible, etc.

Instead of catching any error, this code just throws the "Login timeout expired" and "network-related or instance-specific error has occurred..." error and ceases execution of the rest of the code.

Is my SQL TRY...CATCH block not set up correctly?

Comment: What is the severity of the error you are getting? If its higher than 20, try catch will not trap the error

Comment: How can I tell what the severity of the error is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the MSDN, what [sp_testlinkedserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189809.aspx) do is

> Tests the connection to a linked server. If the test is unsuccessful
>   the procedure raises an exception with the reason of the failure.

So when you compile your code (SP), `sp_testlinkedserver` checks for connection. But you can defer this and capture it by using dynamic SQL.

Like this -

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC sp_testlinkedserver [192.168.51.81];';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'LinkedServerDown' AS Result
END CATCH
```

Comment: I wish this worked! But instead I get the same error messages and results as before.

Comment: @Dezryth: I have checked above code in my sql server instance and it works perfectly fine. see my edited answer(included my local linked server ip).

Comment: @Dezryth: Remove quote(`'`) from the statement and try this query - `EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC sp_testlinkedserver [MyLinkedServer];'`

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)

> **Errors Unaffected by a TRY…CATCH Construct**
>
> TRY…CATCH constructs do not trap the following conditions:
>
> 1. Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or
>      lower.
> 2. Errors that have a severity of 20 or higher that stop the SQL Server
>      Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error occurs
>      that has severity of 20 or higher and the database connection is not
>      disrupted, TRY…CATCH will handle the error.
> 3. Attentions, such as client-interrupt requests or broken client
>      connections.
> 4. When the session is ended by a system administrator by using the
>      KILL statement.
>
> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
>   they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> 1. Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from
>      running.
> 2. Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as
>      object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because
>      of deferred name resolution.

Comment: So basically, I can't do what I'm trying to do here? I want to be able to test if a server is up before running some subsequent code that accesses that server. If not, return some default selection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your end testlinkedserver stored procedure. This will also capture login time out errors.

```
exec dbo.USP_testlinkedserver 'myServerNameHere'
```

The definition is mentioned below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_testlinkedserver 
    @ServerName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX), @errorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @statement = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY('+QUOTENAME(@ServerName,'[')+', ''SELECT 1'')'

BEGIN TRY
    -- run the query
    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @statement;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- show custom message
    SET @errorMessage=QUOTENAME(@ServerName,'[') + ' linked server is not available. ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    Raiserror(@errorMessage,16,1)
END CATCH;

END
```